# How do I change the font size in NCSIM gui?

Tags: specman

We are using specman with NCSIM (IUS 12.2) in GUI mode.
I saw the answer on how to change the specview gui font settings, it works with Specview but not with the NCSIM gui.
How can we make the same thing for the simulator?

Answer (score 3):

Currently there is no Simvision command or menu selection that will change the font size. 
However, there is an alternate approach that you can use. Look for a file called
'Xdefaults' under your .simvision directory in your home directory ($HOME).
i.e. ~/.simvision/Xdefaults

If not, do the following:
There is a file called SimVision under
/share/cdssetup/simvision/app-defaults/
Copy the file 'SimVision' to ~/.simvision and name it 'Xdefaults'.
Now edit this Xdefaults file. It will have a section which looks like this,

! global settings
Simvision*foreground: black
Simvision*background: #dfdfdf
Simvision*Font: -adobe-helvetica-medium-r-normal--12-*-*-*-*-*-*-*

Change the last line above to:
Simvision*Font: -adobe-helvetica-medium-r-normal--18-*-*-*-*-*-*-*

or any other suitable number besides the default 12 to suit your needs.
Save this file and now invoke SimVision - you should see the font sizes increased.
In general, you can review and edit the Xdefaults file above to change the fonts of various windows.
For example - to change the font of the Source Browser - you can locate the following line in the Xdefaults file and edit it :
Simvision*SrcBrowser.fixedFont: -*-courier-medium-r-normal--12-*
Simvision*SrcBrowser.valueFont: -*-courier-medium-r-normal--10-*

1. Change Fonts of 'Cursor' & 'Cursor - Baseline'on Waveform Browser by adding following in /.simvision/Xdefaults
   Simvision*WaveSet.deltaFont:
2. Change Fonts of 'Current time in the simulator'on Waveform Browser by adding following in ~/.simvision/Xdefaults

Comment: How do you change the fonts in the waveform viewer?

Comment: Very useful. Echoing @Veridian Q: How do you change font colors and sizes in  specific windows like waveform viewer or cursor window?